# Is the following SQL query correct for counting the multiple fields from table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(
  "Select count(*) from user where username=? OR email=? OR phone=?"
);
int c = 0;

while (rs1.next()) {
    c++;
}
```

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: no, it is not. The placeholders in the query never get replaced. Then you seem to count the number of rows of the ResultSet. That is wrong since your query already returns a numerical value due to the ``count(*)``.

Answer (score 3):

Your code have some issues :

- First you should use `PreparedStatement` because you are using `?` placeholder
- You should not using while because your query return **only one result**

Instead your code should look like :

```
String query= "Select count(*) as cnt from user where username=? OR email=? OR phone=?";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);) {
    pstmt.setString(1, username);
    pstmt.setString(2, email);
    pstmt.setString(3, phone);
    ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();
    long c = 0;
    if(rs1.next()){
        c = rs1.getLong("cnt");
    }
}
```